# Configuration file error while consuming Wcf service with Ajax Request

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, jquery

I have facing a problem in consuming WCF service using jquery. I have got error "Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/webHttpbinding' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly."

Here is my Web.Config file:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestfulServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebServiceBehavior">

          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.RestfulServiceImp" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RestfulServiceBehavior" 
             bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" binding="webHttpbinding" contract="WcfService1.IRestfulServiceImp"/>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IRestfulServiceImp"/>-->
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IRestfulServiceImp"/>
      </service>
    </services> 
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"
   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
   initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

This is my service name RestfulServiceImp and my Contract is IRestfulServiceImp
Please need your valuable suggestions regarding these.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a case mismatch in your config,

```
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

and

```
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RestfulServiceBehavior" 
             bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" binding="webHttpbinding" contract="WcfService1.IRestfulServiceImp"/>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IRestfulServiceImp"/>-->
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IRestfulServiceImp"/>
```

Check the case difference in webHttpBinding.. you have used **webHttpbinding** instead of **webHttpBinding.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VS open at the moment to look, but be sure that case isn't important.

```
'system.serviceModel/bindings/webHttpbinding
```

vs

```
<webHttpBinding>
```

EDIT: So I opened up VS and changed the binding name to a lower-case and got the same error. Try fixing your case difference.

[image]